# Where to put utility scripts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have some command-line ruby scripts for things like pre-processing text files before uploading them and scraping data.

These scripts don't rely on the rails environment, so I don't really want to make them rake tasks with the associated overhead.

Where should I put them in my folder layout? `lib/utility/` or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We put ours either into the top level of `lib/` or we break them down further like `lib/reports` or `lib/stats`.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Do you have tests for your scripts? parallel directories under test/, or should I not conflate them with the actual app tests?

Comment: We actually haven't created tests for them yet, just because they're easy to test functionally by running them. We've talked about it and thought about using your first suggestion (parallel directories under `test/`), but not 100% set on that yet.